# Dell Optiplex 7010 Drivers do not install correctly during SCCM 2007 Deployment

Tags: deployment, dell, drivers, sccm, sccm-2007

I'm not sure if this the correct place to post this question, so if that's the case I'm sorry!

I am currently working my way through SCCM 2007, as we are required to get all of the companies PCs up to Windows 7 by April 2015. Currently I have driver injection working for OptiPlex 760, 780, and 790. However, whenever I begin my deployment for the Dell Optiplex 7010, the deployment will fail as soon as  it is required to install any applications. On further research this is because there were no network drivers installed on the PC whatsoever. But they are clearly in the driver Packages in SCCM.

I have done nothing dissimilar to the 3 other PCs, so I am slightly perplexed as to why the 7010 would be any different when deploying Windows. If anyone has any impression as to why this may have happened, or had the same experience and found a work around or a fix, please could you give me some advise!

Thanks.

Comment: What do the logs say? Do you know where the logs are located? At what step does it fail? Can you post your TS Steps?

Comment: I know where the logs are stored, I will dig them out and put them online for anyone to view. Technically speaking, the task sequence fails at the point where it is required to start installing applications because they're located on our SCCM server. But as there are no network drivers on the PC it obviously cannot access the network share.

Comment: Here is a link to confirm the drivers haven't installed correctly: http://postimg.org/image/mejctwtjp/ the smsts log tries to connect to the SMSPKGE$ folder but just states that it's failed to connect, and repeats that process for every other folder that the applications are located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optiplex 7010 has a new Intel chipset which requires Windows Kernel Mode Driver Framework v 1.11.  Your NIC will not be detected properly unless the KMDF is patched during the initial deployment. (before reboot).

I cannot recall if the Win PE 4 image has what you need or if your boot.wim would also need to be patched (You could always use a later version of WinPE to put down a Win7 image.)

This is the best link I've found for the issue:  https://deploymentramblings.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/osd-injecting-the-windows-7-kernel-mode-driver-framework-kmdf/

The KMDF patch should go in the Postinstall phase of OSD.

Comment: oh hai, I thought I answered a very similar question recently.  http://serverfault.com/a/649516/255009

Comment: Just to note, From the link you pasted the correct answer marked is to redo the wim images to include the new drivers.

Comment: yes, it was a similar question, but not identical.  In this question, the users seems to be able to do the WinPE portion okay, but the resulting install image has no functioning network device.

Comment: ok! well seem the case there too unless iam mistaking :) As that fail when he push new app after the initial deployment

Comment: Thanks guys! I will read through the posts provided and see whether this will be of any use to me and I'll get back to you! If in the mean time you find anything you think is relevant please comment the link so I can review it :)

Comment: As far as the issues of the drivers not installing correctly has now been solved and that post you provided has worked fantastically! For some reason it did not join the domain? but I will further investigate this.

Comment: Just as a heads up for anyone having the same issue, this worked perfectly. The domain issue was something unrelated to do with permissions!